# Easy to implement secure PHP login with 'secret_token' for queries

Tags: php, authentication

I'm programming a C# Desktop photo application which requires users login/logout, stock photos in a server, share photos. I'm wondering if there are already open-source, easy to implement secure (and using temporary tokens) login library/example for desktop application.

I'm searching for something that makes it easy to build requests similar to: https://myphp_system.com/userid1847236/getphoto?secret_token=cj58sghcvz63jh0nar42vco669dnhx6g

What I want is to avoid things like brute-force attacks or SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I think OAuth is the word you want

Comment: But would users need to connect with Facebook, Twitter, etc, or I could implement my own oAuth authorization system on my website?

Comment: I've read a lot of tutorials, and it is often about 'implement twitter oauth on your website'. What about 'Implement your oauth system on your website'? Just don't know where and what to search.

Comment: There's a Django implementation of oAuth http://code.larlet.fr/django-oauth/wiki/Home but I wonder if there are very generic implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own here's a [tutorial](http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5/) service and include other like twitter, facebook, etc